# how to get a particular cell value from dynamic table using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a table showing records from database. There is a dropdown for selecting a particular user in each row. On change, it should show the corresponding values of the new user.

When I'm selecting a particular user from the dropdown, it should match the col1 and col2 value with the user selected and return col3 value. What I want is to get the col1 and col2 value of that particular row. How can I do it ? Please help me.

Comment: Could you please post your code, or a link to a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Rather than querying the DOM to extract data, have you considered returning the data from the server in an alternate form (eg. JSON)? Trying to extract tabular data _out_ of a table sounds like bad design to me.

Comment: Have you tried using `.rows` and `.cells` properties?

Comment: sorry guys. I cant post my codes here.

Comment: thanks for replying.. i'm trying using .rows but how to know which row's dropdown is being changed, so that the corresponding column values will be fetched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `live('click', function()`. This will apply on dynamically created elements.

For example, you may try something like;

```
$('#your_table_id .some_class_in_a_row_to_click').live('click', function(){
    $(this).siblings().each(function(){
      var column = $(this).find('.some_class_for_column_with_data');
      var data = column.text();
      alert(data);
    });
});
```

You may apply this on a table having some columns. Clicking on some column with class `some_class_in_a_row_to_click` will alert text on another column in that row having class `some_class_for_column_with_data`

Comment: this would work if i was using onclick() on cells. but i want this functionality in onchange() function..

could u help me..